# Error while creating Account using SOAP UI 5.6.0

Tags: soap-api, soap

*While creating a Request in SOAP UI I am getting an error. The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:type" associated with an element type "urn:sObjects" is not bound.  Not sure how to fix this issue.*

**REQUEST:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
 
      <urn:SessionHeader>
       <urn:sessionId>REDACTED</urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:create>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <urn:sObjects xsi:type="Áccount" xmls:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <Name>Arvind External Systems Account</Name>
         </urn:sObjects>
      </urn:create>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**ERROR:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:type" associated with an element type "urn:sObjects" is not bound.</faultstring>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please do not include session Ids. I've redacted it, but it is still visible in your edit history. Please invalidate/log out of the session as soon as possible to avoid security problems.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, you must bind it to `urn1`, as defined at the top of the SOAP message:

```
     <urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:Áccount">
        <Name>Arvind External Systems Account</Name>
     </urn:sObjects>
```

See Scenario 2 on [the sample API page](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/salesforce-soap-api-sample-wsdls.html).

Comment: <urn:sObjects xsi:type="Student__c" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Student_Name_c>Arvind External Systems Account</Student_Name_c>
         </urn:sObjects>



The above code worked for me. But only for custom objects. I couldn't make it work for standard object Account.